# How to view or scroll a long expression in the Chrome Dev Tools Watch Panel?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, watch

As you can see in the following screenshot, I'm forced to try to discern the value from a very long variable name. For some reason though, you can't scroll Chrome's (v81) Watch panel horizontally to view the rest of the truncated value. Is there really no way to see this value without stretching the window as far as possible?

[image: Chrome Dev Tools screenshot of Watch Panel with variable key truncated at the edge of the screen]

Comment: It's an annoying bug, please report it on https://crbug.com. It was reported in 2013 (https://crbug.com/237857) but slipped through the cracks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an annoying bug which makes the watch panel unusable in lots of cases.

A temporary workaround for the duration of this devtools session in this tab is to patch the devtools itself by running the following code in **devtools-on-devtools**.

1. switch to `Sources` panel
2. expand `Watch` and make sure at least one expression is present
3. open **devtools-on-devtools** and run the following code
4. close devtools-on-devtools

```js
(() => {
  try {
    UI.panels.sources
      ._watchSidebarPane[UI.View.widgetSymbol || UI.View._widgetSymbol]
      ._watchExpressions[0]._element.getRootNode()
      .appendChild(document.createElement('style')).textContent = `
        .watch-expression-title {
          display: flex;
        }
        .name {
          max-width: 50%;
          overflow: hidden;
          text-overflow: ellipsis;
        }
        `;
  } catch (e) {
    console.warn('Add an expression and expand the Watch list.');
  }
})();
```

---

For convenience you can save the code in [snippets](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/snippets) and run it later from there or by typing the snippet name in the commands palette (<kbd>Ctrl-P</kbd> or <kbd>Cmd-P</kbd> hotkey).

#### How to open devtools-on-devtools:

1. Open devtools first and switch its `Dock side` in the menu to a detached (floating) window

   [image]
2. in the now detached devtools press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>i</kbd> or <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>i</kbd> on MacOS,
   which will open **devtools-on-devtools** in a new window

Comment: Wow, this is fancy. Very interesting. Also, bizarre this sort of basic usability has been neglected so long?

Comment: One note, it may need to be `UI.View._widgetSymbol`, that seemed to work for me.

Comment: It turns out I was actually on Chrome 79, so maybe that property has been updated.

Comment: I've added the variant for an older Chrome.